# Workspace of eclipse not building

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, program-entry-point

I have imported a project from svn in eclipse. But building workspace does not seem to work and class files are not getting generated. As a result I am getting error like "could not load or find main...".
So far I tried configuring build path, project facets, cleaning workspace. But all in vain.

Please suggest any fix for this.

Comment: make sure you do have "Build Automatically" on (Menu -> Project) and no red explamation marks or x' on the project. An you need to have Java Nature and Java Builder enabled on the project (have a look at the .project file)

Comment: A red exclamation mark is there on the project. What does that signify?

Comment: It says the Project Setup is not ok. it may be caused by a missing source folder or missing libs etc. (have a look at the problem view)

Comment: Fixed the red mark. Working fine now @ChristianDietrich. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It means there is a problem with the `build path` in your project.

Check the Build Path of the project by right clicking the project and select `Build Path -> Configure Build Path`.

There is a Problems view (try `Window->Show View`)

Also can be related to JRE version being used